# How to add a constraint in mysql that checks if only certain couples of value is unique without to put both columns in a unique constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, unique

I have a table in a mysql database that is similiar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_shop` (
      `customer_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
      `shop_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
      `main` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false
)
```

For each customer in the table there must be at most 1 main pharmacy, this means that there mustn't be 2 records with the same customer_id and main = true.
It's like to have a unique constraints on the couple (customer_id, main) valid only when main = true.

Is it possible to create a constraint with this condition?
I've searched a bit, and I've found something similiar (somebody talks about filtered unique indexes) but I haven't understood how to apply them to my case.

Comment: 'filtered unique indexes' - mysql does not have this feature consider a trigger instead..

Comment: If you index (customer_id, main) then you can do a quick look-up before updating main to true. You would have to be careful to avoid race conditions etc. though.

Comment: Or you could move main shop id to customer..

Comment: @P.Salmon I would like but I can't, and also I would have to add a different check to select main shop only if is present in this table.

Comment: How can I do the other solutions you said? I'm not so pratical with SQL for a while